# WSO2 Identity Server - Federated SAML using WSO2 as Proxy Server?

Tags: wso2, server, identity, saml

Could you please clarify if there is a chance to interconnect a WSO2 Identity Server with an existing corporate IdP using the SAML as federated connection mechanism. What exactly needs to be configured to unify the realm and proxy the authentication with the external IDP?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WSO2 IS as a proxy or a federation bus, then you need to register your IDP and Service provider in WSO2 IS and in your IDP you should register WSO2 IS as a service provider.

If you use WSO2 IS as your service provider, you need to register your existing IDP in WSO2 IS as IDP and WSO2 as service provider in you IDP side.

You can follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Working+with+Identity) document for more information.

Thanks!